# Where to put web scrape logic in MVC

Tags: asp.net-core, model-view-controller

I'm building a .NET Core MVC application. It has a single endpoint that retrieves an imdb id of a movie by scraping the imdb site. So my question is, where do I put the logic to get the id? My original project structure is shown below.

```
+--Controller
  +--Entry point api call
+--Logic
  +--Class that retrieves imdbId
+--Models
  +--Models
  +--Context
```

So I was originally going to put the logic where it retrieves the id in the "Logic" folder and call it from the Controller. I was also going to instantiate the model and store it in the DB here. I also do request validation in the controller and make sure the given movie title and release year are correct format.

I'm starting to think this is incorrect though? Should I put request validation and id retrieval in the model layer? Any help on how to approach this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So I was originally going to put the logic where it retrieves the id in the "Logic" folder and call it from the Controller.

This is what I would do too. ID retrieval is not a concern of the controller (the presentation layer does not care how you retrieve the ID) so it should be placed in a separate layer.

> Should I put request validation and id retrieval in the model layer?

No, because this does not pertain to the models. The model layer should just contain the classes for your models. I would put request validation in the controller (presentation layer).

My suggestion is that your original project structure works fine. Within the logic layer, I would further separate concerns among different services, so that the ID retrieval functionality would reside in a separate service from the DB storage functionality (DB management could also be a separate layer on its own).

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you put it in the Logic class, so you can unit test the logic outside of the model. Your models should be super simple, just properties, and if there is some other internal logic they need.

The http call you will need to make I would put in your logic and ensure you are using some interface for your http client so you can create moqs for easier unit testing.